# Layout messed up in Firefox - Columns?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Please take a look at this screenshot. Layout is fine for other browsers but firefox.

Here's is the column code

```html
.column, .columns {
  padding-left: 0.625rem;
  padding-right: 0.625rem;
  width: 100%;
  float: left; 
  
  }
```

[Screenshot of site firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvWcA.jpg)

[website url](http://www.customlogoshop.com)

Comment: Have you set a `box-sizing: border-box;` on the items?

Comment: No not set on anything

Comment: what does this effect @Roy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Firefox and the url works fine in my end. It doesn't look like your screenshot. It could be your Firefox settings.